# Unable to restrict access to the post edit screen with django

Tags: django

I am restricting access to the posted edit screen.
I want to make sure that only the user who posted or the super user can edit the post.
For that purpose, "UserPassesTestMixin" is used.

However, there is no limit.
And I think that my own "OnlyRecordEditMixin" is not responding. If you understand, thank you.

```
#mixin
class OnlyRecordEditMixin(UserPassesTestMixin):
  raise_exception = True

  def test_func(self):
    user = self.request.user
    id = self.kwargs['id']
    print(id)
    return user.pk == URC.objects.get(id=id).user or user.is_superuser
```

```py
#view
class RecordDetailEdit(UpdateView,OnlyRecordEditMixin):
    template_name = 'records/detail_edit.html'
    model = URC
    pk_url_kwarg = 'id'
    form_class = RecordDetailEditForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('person:home')

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
      obj = URC.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['id'])
      return obj
```

```
#url
path('<id>/edit/', views.RecordDetailEdit.as_view(), name='record_detail_edit'),
```

```
#model
class URC(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Here: `return user.pk == URC.objects.get(id=id).user` => you're comparing a PK to a  `User` object. You want either `user.pk == URC.objects.get(id=id).user_id` or `user == URC.objects.get(id=id).user`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out.
I corrected it as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **mixin should be put *before* the base view class**, to construct a good MRO here.

```
class RecordDetailEdit(OnlyRecordEditMixin, UpdateView):
    template_name = 'records/detail_edit.html'
    model = URC
    pk_url_kwarg = 'id'
    form_class = RecordDetailEditForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('person:home')
```

You should *not* override the `get_object(..)` method here. The `get_object(..)` method is defined in terms of `get_queryset(..)`: it filters the `get_queryset(..)` with the given primary key (and/or slug).

You can however easily restrict access by restricting the `get_queryset`:

```
class OnlyRecordEditMixin(LoginRequiredMixin):

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.user.is_superuser:
            return qs.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return qs
```

or even more generic:

```
class OnlyRecordEditMixin(LoginRequiredMixin):

    user_field = 'user'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.user.is_superuser:
            return qs.filter(**{self.user_field: self.request.user})
        return qs
```

Here we can thus change the `user_field` to point to the name that is the *owner* of the object.

This will return a HTTP 404 response if a user that is not a superuser, nor the "owner" of the object aims to update that object.

This is cheaper, since you prevent fetching the object multiple times.

Comment: It's amazing. Genius. I did it. Thank you very much.